# HVAC breaker issue

Tags: hvac

My HVAC (Tempstar 5300XL) comes on automatically at the preset temperature. It may run cold for 45 minutes to an hour, then trips the breaker.  What is the most logical problem, and solution?

Comment: Which breaker is tripping? There a 4 possible breakers: air handler breaker in the main breaker panel, condenser breaker in the main panel, local breaker for the air handler, and local breaker for the condenser. Note that you probably don't have all 4 breakers.

Comment: What is the outdoor ambient air temperature? What is the thermostat set point? Is the indoor temperature changing properly?

Comment: The condenser breaker trips. It is a 30 amp breaker, with the minimum required per spec of 23amps. Air handler is fine.  The outdoor temperature is usually in the 80's, and the set point inside at the thermostat is 77. I am at approx 6800 feet above sea level, in the foothills of the Rockies.

Comment: The system spec calls for a max breaker of 40 amps.  Should I replace with another 30 amp, or a 40amp breaker?  Relative Humidity in the summer averages around 40%

Comment: Please *DO NOT* replace the 30 amp breaker with a 40.  The breaker is there to protect the wiring in the house and you must never ever increase a breaker rating without making certain the wire is sized for it (it usually is not).  Anyway, a 30 amp breaker is all that is needed if the MCA is 23 amps.  Please see my answer below for other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more specific information the best I can do is play the odds.  Assuming this is a new problem on a system that otherwise worked reliably in the past, the most likely issues are:

1. Dirty condenser coil (Wash the dirt out with a hose spray attachment).
2. Weak condenser fan capacitor.  (Verify that the condenser fan spins the correct direction, not backward, when unit is running.  Check the fan capacitor with capacitance a meter.  If it is less than 90% of the labeled value, replace it.)
3. Weak compressor capacitor.  (Check the compressor capacitor with a meter.  If it is less than 90% of the labeled value, replace it.)
4. There could be a loose connection at the breaker box like Speedy Petey suggests.  If so, the breaker should be very warm to the touch after the unit has been running.  To rule this out, after 30 minutes of operation touch the face of the breaker to check if it is very much warmer than the other breakers.

Please remember to always turn the disconnect OFF before doing any service work inside any equipment.  Also, there are other issues that can cause this overload problem, but in my experience they are less likely on a system that was previously working.

Comment: I followed your recommendations, and after allowing the system to run for a couple of days, the "fix" was a combination of #1 cleaning the coils, and #4 tightening the cables at the outside breaker box(sub panel and main panel cables checked out ok).  Thank you for a logical and systematic approach to correcting the problem. My daughters friend, in the HVAC business in FL, recommended replacing the entire system at a cost of $4k!!!  Great work!

Answer (score 1):

IMO the most likely culprit for an A/C tripping a properly sized breaker is a poor connection/corrosion at the breaker. The breaker gets hot and tricks the thermal trip mechanism into opening the breaker.